# How to block endpoints by condition. AntMatchers does not recognize path variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, endpoint

I have a Spring Boot application, with a property in the `.properties` file. I would like to be able to block/enable some endpoints based on condition.

I've currently created two beans annotated with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, so they enable/disable based on the value.

The beans contain the Spring Security configuration.

Let's take this configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
         .antMatcher("/api/test/**")
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/api/test/{ID}").authenticated()
             .antMatchers("/api/test/hello/hello2").authenticated()
             .anyRequest().denyAll();
}
```

If inside my controller I have three endpoints:

- `/api/test/{ID}`
- `/api/test/hello/hello2`
- `/api/test/bye`

it happens that by specifying in Spring Security

```java
.antMatchers("/api/test/{ID}").authenticated()
```

`/api/test/bye` is also enabled (should be blocked as `denyAll()` is there), because Spring obviously doesn't know what {ID} can contain. So I wanted to understand how I could block endpoints by specifying paths. Even not using Spring Security. Maybe if there is an alternative.

I don't want to have to specify all the endpoints one by one and apply the rules to each one, I want to specify only the one to be "unblocked" and all the rest blocked automatically.

Furthermore, I don't want to use regexes for path variables, because there are cases in which path variables are strings and therefore I would have the same problem.

Comment: I would say your URLs are not well defined. You shouldn't have an endpoint with ID and a named sub resource. In the rare case that you really need duplicated meanings, you should add a rule. That would also improve the understanding of your configuration.